# Creating a textbox with predefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing problem in creating a text box for email address which I want to be already filled up by example: @hotmail.com so that only the actual identifier be entered by the user, I want to do this in a single text box.
Is it possible? as i remember I have seen it somewhere on websites.

Comment: are you talking about placeholders?

Comment: Can't you use `<input type="email" value="@hotmail.com">` ?

Comment: Why not just have the username in the textbox, and `@hotmail.com` following it? It's probably also worthwhile Including some validation to stop the user putting characters like `@` in their username.

Comment: that wouldn't send "@hotmail.com" to server. Remember the box has to be used for email log in.

Comment: @Adrian Wragg Actually its the requirement from the client that ive to make it inside single text box. what ive understood is i would need to make "@abc.com" read only but in same text box.

Comment: can you add the code fragment that you used for this or can you add the expected output for your question and may i know do you want some think  like placeholders

Comment: requirement is not very clear...are you saying the domain will always be known? If so is simple to concatenate name and domain before sending to server or have server do concatenation

Comment: @charlietfl yes i want a constant domain to be used every time user login, only the other part of email shall be entered.

Comment: @Revanth Rev your answer is partially right, but i want to do that with using single text box.

Comment: so domain doesn't need to be in the `input` value at all... then it's just a matter of style and concatenation either at server or in UI. Seems trivial

Comment: Try it now @atif ...
i tried it in my way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of approach may fulfill your need

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('#in').val();
    var domain = $('#dom').val();
    alert(name + domain);
});
```

```css
#in{
  border-right:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
 }
#dom{
  border-left:0px;
  margin-left:-5px;
  padding-left:0px;
  text-align:right;
  width:108px
 }
input{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in"/>
<input id="dom" readonly value="@example.com"/>
<button>Subscribe</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: the above solution is partially right, but i want to do that in single text box

Comment: try it now ... i hope this now work... not exactly but, almost

Comment: waow, that seems interesting.

Comment: On focus it seems odd in chrome but in firefox no problems. working on it and will come to a solution @atif :)

Comment: will it send @example.com to database? Because these are actually 2 textboxes joined together

Comment: you can get those values on some events and concatenate them... i'll update above answer for your need...

Comment: sure sure :D @yshavit

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').blur(function(){
     var mailname=$(this).val();
     var mailprovider=$('span').text();
     alert(mailname+mailprovider);
    });
});
```

```css
#uname{
    padding:7px;
    width:256px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:none;
}
span.hid {
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:6px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:none;
    right:15px;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="uname" value=""><span class="hid">@hotmail.com</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is easily faked using a hidden `input` that will only be seen by the server.

In your page, add the following HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='username'> @hotmail.com
<input name='email' type='hidden' />
```

and, in your initialisation procedure, add the following:

```
$("#username").bind("blur", function() {
    $("input[name = 'email']").val($(this).val() + "@hotmail.com"); 
});
```

This will populate the hidden `input` when focus is lost from the visible one, populating it with `<username>@hotmail.com`.

I've created a fiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qcqmfrv6/1/), albeit with the hidden input changed to a normal text input so the result can be seen.